# Given a point and distance , is it possible to get the second point on the line + three dimensional points

Tags: geometry

Im trying to find out is there any possibility of find a second point(three dimensional) which is located at a distance from the first point on the line.

For Eg: I have a point A(3,1,4) and given distance is 5. How can i find the other point B with respect to A and distance A on a line.

Comment: The whole sphere $(x-3)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-4)^2=25$ could be the point B. Or do you mean a line is also given?

Comment: A line is given .I have a point A which lies on that line . I also have a distance for other point to lie on the same line. how to find the other point from distance x from given point

Comment: You can use the intersection of the line and the sphere. Or if you have the parametric equation, you can use the direction vector. Divide it by its norm and multiply by 5, then add it to A.

Comment: Can you please suggest me with some example . I have completely forgot all the concepts long back.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, if the point $A$ is on the line

$$x=1-t\\
y=5+2t\\
z=2-3t$$

The direction vector of the line is $(-1, 2, -3)$ (the coefficients of $t$). Norm of the direction vector is $\sqrt{(-1)^2+2^2+(-3)^2}=\sqrt{14}$. Now from your point $A$, you would add $5$ times the unit direction, which is then

$$(3,1,4)+\frac{5}{\sqrt{14}}(-1,2,-3)=(3-\frac{5}{\sqrt{14}}, 1+\frac{10}{\sqrt{14}}, -3-\frac{15}{\sqrt{14}})$$